# Schema validation error when accepting datetime

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsd-validation, ibm-datapower

We have field in an XML which will have date along with Timestamp.

EX : 2016-12-22 10:36:46

and in our Schema, we have defined that element as

```
<xs:element name="REJECTTIME" minOccurs="0"  type="xs:datetime"/>
```

But we are getting a fatal error as below

> Element has type={http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}datetime, which
>   does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be

```
type="xs:dateTime"
             ^
```

instead of

```
type="xs:datetime"
```

Comment: thx for the quick reply....

But xs:dateTime will accept date and time with "T"

<REJECTTIME>2016-12-22T10:36:46</REJECTTIME>

do we have any datetype which will accept the date and time in the below format

<REJECTTIME>2016-12-22 10:36:46</REJECTTIME>

Comment: You could use a `xs:string` data type and add a `pattern`  restriction.